# how to create deadlock situation in the oracle on a table which is having simple 4 columns(sno,name,job,dept)?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, deadlock

i wanted to create a deadlock situation in the oracle table which will not give response and will be hang on executing the same query from the java application ?Could you please provide one sample query which makes this situation on a table (having 4 columns sno,name,job,dept ) .

Comment: Do you mean *deadlock* or just a *lock*?  A deadlock is a specific kind of lock, and would not make things hang but would quickly cause an error and break one of the processes.

Comment: i wanted to make deadlock to the sessions

Answer (score 4):

In session 1:

```
DECLARE
  v_row1 TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE;
  v_row2 TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO   v_row1
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  sno = 1
  FOR UPDATE;

  DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP( seconds => 5 );

  SELECT *
  INTO   v_row2
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  sno = 2
  FOR UPDATE;

  ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

Then in session 2:

```
DECLARE
  v_row1 TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE;
  v_row2 TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  INTO   v_row2
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  sno = 2
  FOR UPDATE;

  DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP( seconds => 5 );

  SELECT *
  INTO   v_row1
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  sno = 1
  FOR UPDATE;

  ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

Comment: thank you for answer , i am trying to make this situation ..let you know the result

Comment: Another way is to do updates to rows in session 1 and do not commit them and then try to do updates to the same rows in session 2. Session 2 will hang until session 1 either does a commit or rollback.

Answer (score 1):

A deadlock occurs when two or more sessions are waiting for data locked by each other, resulting in all the sessions being blocked. Typically, deadlocks are caused by poorly implemented locking in application code or due to a performance issue or due to a conflict between two different process processing data on the DB.

Refer : https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/deadlocks

Comment: thank you for answer , i am trying to make this situation ..let you know the result